# Testing/Mocking AuthUserSession in Servicestack Ormlite with MVC

Tags: unit-testing, ormlite-servicestack

I have an existing MCV application that uses ServiceStack Ormlite. I am adding some controller tests and can mock injected classes without issue, however we are having problems with the ServiceStack AuthUserSession which is used by some controllers to check permissions and other properties of the session.

All the controllers inherit from the base controller `_Controller` which has the following property:

`public MyAuthUserSession AuthUserSession => SessionAs<MyAuthUserSession>();`

`MyAuthUserSession` extends the `AuthUserSession` class and has some extra methods and data members.

In the controllers we use this property to check permissions for particular cases:

`model.CanEdit = AuthUserSession.HasEntityPermission(PermissionType.Update, PermissionEntity.MyEntity);`

However when running as a unit test, calling `AuthUserSession` always throws a null reference exception.

I've attempted to populate the session by including a test AppHost:

```
public class TestAppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public TestAppHost() : base("Test Service", typeof(LocationsService).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new MyAuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[] { new BasicAuthProvider() })
        {
            IncludeAssignRoleServices = false,
            IncludeAuthMetadataProvider = false,
            IncludeRegistrationService = false,
            GenerateNewSessionCookiesOnAuthentication = false,
            DeleteSessionCookiesOnLogout = true,
            AllowGetAuthenticateRequests = req => true
        });
    }
}
```

Which takes the same arguments as the main application, however the AuthUserSession is never populated. I've tried setting it manually:

```
var authService = appHost.Container.Resolve<AuthenticateService>();
var session = new MyAuthUserSession();
authService.SaveSessionAsync(session).Wait();
```

Manually setting a session doesn't work - I suspect the saved session is not associated with the controller's `SessionAs<MyAuthUserSession>()`.

This is starting to look closer to an integration test than a unit test, but essentially I just need the `AuthUserSession` property on the base controller to return a session for testing, either by setting it manually or by mocking it. Since this is a legacy application changing the `AuthUserSession` property on the controller is not practical (there are perhaps 1000 references to it, so changing it will require a huge amount of refactoring). Since it is a regular property I cannot substitute the response with NSubstitute (eg. `MyController.AuthUserSession.Returns(new MyAuthUserSession()`)

Is there any way of setting or substituting the `SessionAs<MyAuthUserSession>()` method in Servicestack or the `AuthUserSession` property on a controller?

EDIT:

I've added the following lines to my AppHost with no changes:

```
TestMode = true;
container.Register<IAuthSession>(new MyAuthUserSession { UserAuthId = "1" });
```

I also attempted to add the session to the request items via the controller's `ControllerContext.HttpContext` with no success.

Since most examples I can find are for testing APIs I had a look at writing tests for our Servicestack API, and for the API registering the IAuthSession as above is all that's needed, it just works. Doing the same thing in the MVC application doesn't seem to work. I'm struggling to find the difference between the two.

The service has the session defined as:

```
public class WebApiService : Service
{
    public AuthUserSession AuthUserSession => SessionAs<AuthUserSession>();

...
}
```

And any services inheriting from `WebApiService` have access to the AuthUserSession.

On the base controller in the MVC application I have:

```
public abstract class _Controller : ServiceStackController
{
    public AuthUserSession => SessionAs<MyAuthUserSession>();
    ...
}
```

The AppHosts for both the API and MVC controller tests are identical and both register the IAuthSession session the same way. There's got to be something very simple difference between the `ServiceStack.Mvc.ServiceStackController` and the `ServiceStack.Service` or how I'm using them.

EDIT: Including stack trace:

```
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at ServiceStack.Host.NetCore.NetCoreRequest.TryResolve[T]()
at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.GetCacheClient(IRequest req)
at ServiceStack.ServiceStackProvider.get_Cache()
at ServiceStack.ServiceStackProvider.SessionAs[TUserSession]()
at ServiceStack.Mvc.ServiceStackController.SessionAs[TUserSession]()
at WebApplication.Controllers._Controller.get_AuthUserSession() in _Controller.cs:line 93
at WebApplication.Controllers.MyController.Common(PageAction action, MyDataModel model) in MyController.cs:line 288
at WebApplication.Controllers.MyController.Show(Int64 id) in MyController.cs:line 157
at WebApplication.UnitTests.Controllers.MyControllerTests.Show_WithReadPrivileges_ReturnsExpectedSettingValue() in MyControllerTests.cs:line 115
```

Where `_Controller` is the base controller which has the `SessionAs` call, and `MyController` is the controller that inherits the base.

EDIT:

I've stripped everything back as far as I can, and still getting a null on the session. My AppHost is taken from the 'Basic Configuration' in the docs, plus a `UnityIocAdapter` for my controller resolution and registering the `IAuthSession` as suggested:

```
public class TestAppHost : BasicAppHost
{
    public TestAppHost() : base(typeof(LocationsService).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        container.Adapter = new UnityIocAdapter(Repository.Container.Instance);
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new BasicAuthProvider(),       //Sign-in with HTTP Basic Auth
        new CredentialsAuthProvider(), //HTML Form post of UserName/Password credentials
    }));

        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
        var userRepo = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
        container.Register<IAuthRepository>(userRepo);
        container.Register<IAuthSession>(new AuthUserSession());
    }
}
```

Using an empty controller with:

```
public class EmptyController: ServiceStackController
{
    public EmptyController() {}

    public AuthUserSession AuthUserSession => SessionAs<AuthUserSession>();
}
```

Calling the following still results in the null exception with the stack trace above:

```
_appHost = new TestAppHost();
_appHost.Init();
var contr = _appHost.Resolve<EmptyController>();
var session = contr.AuthUserSession;
```

Removing the `UnityIocAdapter` and creating a new controller with `new EmptyController()` does the same, but that's far removed from how the controllers are resolved in the application, but I don't know of another way to resolve a controller without more complication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First have a look at [ServiceStack Testing Docs](https://docs.servicestack.net/testing#using-an-in-memory-database) for using a `BasicAppHost` to create a test AppHost which is configured with `Config.TestMode=true` which allows you to register your Session in the IOC:

```cs
container.Register<IAuthSession>(new MyAuthUserSession());
```

Alternatively you can populate a session for a request by setting it in `IRequest.Items` dictionary, e.g:

```cs
service.Request ??= new BasicRequest();
service.Request.Items[Keywords.Session] = new MyAuthUserSession();
```

I've updated the Unit Test example in your [ServicestackAuthExample](https://github.com/TobyODonnell-AIAU/ServicestackAuthExample) repository so it passes:

```cs
// Empty TempData for testing
public class TestDataDictionary : Dictionary<string,object>, ITempDataDictionary
{
    public void Load() {}
    public void Save() {}
    public void Keep() {}
    public void Keep(string key) {}
    public object? Peek(string key) => null;
}

public class Tests
{
    private static TestAppHost _appHost;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _appHost = new TestAppHost();
        _appHost.Init();
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestPrivacyPage()
    {
        // Controllers aren't resolved from ServiceStack IOC
        var sut = new HomeController
        {
            // Returning View() requires TempData
            TempData = new TestDataDictionary()
        };
        // RequestServices needs to be configured to use an IOC
        sut.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext {
            RequestServices = _appHost.Container
        };
        sut.ServiceStackRequest.Items[Keywords.Session] = new AuthUserSession();

        var result = sut.Privacy();
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried the above suggestions but still no success, I've added to the original question to provide details. Essentially, I've managed to get it working in the Servicestack API service by registering the IAuthSession as above, but still no luck with the MVC controller with identical registration and app host.

Comment: For `ServiceStackController` you can try populating `ServiceStackRequest.Items[Keywords.Session]` instead.

Comment: I tried `sut.ServiceStackRequest.Items[Keywords.Session] = new MyAuthUserSession();`, I also tried just with the base AuthUserSession with no luck. Debugging shows that the ServiceStackRequest.Items[0] exists with a key of  "__session" and a value of type "MyAuthUserSession", but `SessionAs<MyAuthUserSession>();` still returns "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')'"

Comment: Can you update your question with the full Exception StackTrace.

Comment: I've added a stack trace above.

Comment: Might be because the `HttpContext` of the Controller is null? Is the MVC Controller's `ControllerContext` populated?

Comment: I didn't think that was related, but it was null and I've been populating it manually when setting up the test with `sut.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();`, where sut is the controller. So it is not null by the time the session is requested.

Comment: I've stripped as much away as I can from the controller and app host, and still have the same issues, added details above.

Comment: It looks like it's failing on [this line](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/69c5bb269fd3a50f7898e74e9b117a810a9ac606/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/Host/NetCore/NetCoreRequest.cs#L53), suggesting the HttpContext isn't properly populated. A workaround you can try in your TestAppHost is to override [GetCacheClient()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/ServiceStackHost.Runtime.cs#L1002) and return the ICacheClient in the IOC

Comment: Calling `AppHost.Instance.Resolve<ServiceStack.Caching.ICacheClient>()` within the controller correctly gets the MemoryCacheClient, as does HostContext.AppHost.GetCacheClient(). I tried overriding on the app host and the result is the same - the cache client is returned when requesting but still the same null reference exception on `SessionAs<AuthUserSession>()`

Comment: I have made a repository as small as I can while still keeping the layout our application uses. Clicking the 'Privacy' link in this repo accesses the AuthUserSession and works in MVC, but accessing the route with the unit tests fails. [Repository Here](https://github.com/TobyODonnell-AIAU/ServicestackAuthExample).

Comment: Please see my updated answer for changes to fix the unit test

Comment: Thanks for all your help, that has fixed it! Setting the `RequestServices = _appHost.Container` line makes all the difference.